# What do you usually do on your day-off? "I usually drive to work"

Tags: exam-questions

What do you usually do on your day-off?

A. I usually drive to work

B. I will sleep all day

C. I usually do not much

D. Nothing much. I always sleep until noon

This is one of the exercises from my handout.  According to the handout the correct answer is option “A”. I am puzzled. I think the correct answer should have been option “D”.

I truly appreciate your help.

[image]

Here is the input I got from my friend on why she thinks that option "A" is the correct choice.

"I think the question is in present tense, so the answer shouldn't be future tense as in option "B". It's not option "C" because in the sentence "do" is the the auxiliary (not after it to make a negative sentence.), but it has the adverb "much" while there is no verb".

Comment: A and D don't make logical sense. B (as you say) is future tense while the question asks about present and recent past. C might be OK as "I usually do *not much*.", but I think people would more likely say "I usually do not *do* much."

Comment: I don't see any reason to say D doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Likely to be a question set by a non-native speaker, applying rules but not thinking about meaning. The best response is D.

A. is grammatically correct, and it answers the question. But the answer doesn't make sense. "Day off" implies you don't have work.

B. Is grammatically well formed, but doesn't answer the question. The question asks for usually, the answer concerns one particular future event.

C. Is not grammatically correct, as it is missing a verb "I usually do not *do* much" would be ok.

D. Is the best response. It means "I usually do nothing much, because I always sleep until noon".

So a simple badly made question, or an error on the part of the test setter. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the other answers would make sense, however **A** is the only one which does not.
"Day off" usually means one does not work nor would one usually go to work.

Comment: B is inappropriate as an answer to the question due to aspect (not tense), although it could make sense in another context. C makes sense, but it should be "I usually **don't do** much."